# py2neo Listing all nodes in DB

Tags: python, py2neo

I'm trying to list all nodes from an index in my neo4j database. The following code works however it only prints out about 600 nodes when I have over 10K in the index. I suspect I'm using the wrong the method. Any help is appreciated.

```
myindex = graph_db.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Node, "nodeID")
allnodes = myindex.query("nodeID:*")
for i in allnodes:
    value1 = "{0}".format(i['nodeID'])
    print value1
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason why that wouldn't work based on what you've posted here. Perhaps you're hitting some kind of limit I haven't yet encountered. Do you have any log output you can post?

If you want to get in touch privately (via email), and are willing to share your source database, I can try to help you solve this particular case and see if a more general issue can be identified.

Comment: I figure it out (kinda). its returning a unicode error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 2, in <module>
    value1 = "{0}".format(i['whoisID'])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)